# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined for search filter

Tags: angular

I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`
I created a custom filter to filter out the search field by name, but I'm getting this error and can't get past it. Any help is appreciated.
Also follow up question. In the latest iteration of Angular2, do we no longer add filter:[FilterArrayPipe], under @Component, but add it via app.module.ts in NGModule declaration?

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
           import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

      @Pipe({name: 'filter'})
      export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform{

      transform(value, args){
    if(!args || !args[0]) {
      return value;

      }

  else if(value) {
    return value.filter(item => {
  for (let key in item){

  if((typeof item[key] === 'string' || item[key] instanceof String)&&
  (item[key].indexOf(args[0]) !== -1)) {
  return true;

  }

  }


    })
  }

  }

  }
```

**users.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Users" [(ngModel)]= "filterText">

      </div><!-- /input-group -->
      <br>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let user of _users | filter: filterText"  >
      <tr>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
          <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: It doesn't specify, but it's the pipe | filter: filterText that is triggering it. See screenshot added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. You are implementing a `tranform` method when it should be `transform`.

It might help you for the next one to import `PipeTransform` and declare your class like `export class FilterArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {` for the TypeScript compiler to fail and warn you about the wrong method.

Comment: Nice catch and I took your advice and implement PipeTransform, but I'm getting a new error now. Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined I updated code above based on your suggestion and screenshot as well

Comment: You are checking if the first element of the array exists but not if the array itself exists, so change your if condition to be `if(!args || !args[0]) {`.